# d3 Xscale returning nan even on setting scale properly

Tags: d3.js

I am creating a d3 line chart, but my XScale is returning nan.

My lines are in ascending order of timestamp
I am setting x domain as:

```
var lastIndex = line_data[0].length -1;
var minDate = line_data[0][0]['date'];
var maxDate = line_data[0][lastIndex]['date'];
x.domain([minDate,maxDate]);
```

later I am trying to access it as:

```
.x(function(d) { console.log('d for x is',d.date);
    console.log(x(d.date));
    return x(d.date); })
```

Why is it returning nan?

Here is my fiddle
https://jsfiddle.net/james222/yw3Le6yb/

Comment: I cannot edit this question because the suggested edit queue is full.  Your fiddle makes it clear that you are using strings instead of dates.  `abc[i]['date'] = parser(dateLabel);` at line 100 converts the date into a string, but you continue to use it as a date.  Please include this line in the original question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are converting a date to a string when populating `line_data`.

```
var parser = d3.time.format("%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S");
abc[i]['date'] = parser(dateLabel);
line_data[counter] = abc;
```

Just use the date here.

```
abc[i]['date'] = dateLabel;
```